# Finding Color Palettes?

Tags: topography, colormap

Anybody can help me to find the three color palettes of the following map?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What software are you using? They don't look like palettes to me, but ramps. In ArcGIS that particular ramp is named "Surface". The first and third images anyway. The second appears to be different because there's no red in it. It might be custom or maybe just doesn't have an equivalent in Arc. My *guess* is that they're all the RGB palette.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, I use the matlab and GMT. The second comes from NASA. I can not find the same color palettes from cpt-city like these images,and try to edit the color bar using matlab,but not succeed.

Comment: I Googled cpt-city and wound up at http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/ where toward the bottom I see [Palettes for Topography](http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/views/topo.html) which has some similar ramps. I noted a few other possibilities further up such as "DEM palettes by Thomas Dewez". Is that what you're after? http://docs.idldev.com/mglib/vis/color/cptcity_catalog.html also has a tremendous number of ramps...

Comment: Yes,Chris. I saw the DEM palettes by Thomas Dewez and the cptcity_catalog similar with these three images,but they are not same. If can not find the same one, I will use these ramps as your advice. Thank you very much!